# How do I use proguard to de-obfuscate an Android stack trace?

Tags: android, proguard

I've downloaded the retrace jar and trying to run it given my mapping file `out.map` and an obfuscated stack trace `crashtrace.txt` taken from Crashlytics.

```
java -jar ~/Downloads/proguard-retrace-4.11.jar -verbose out.map crashtrace.txt
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: proguard/obfuscate/MappingProcessor
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: proguard.obfuscate.MappingProcessor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by downloading the ProGuard distribution from [sourceforge](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) and using that version of retrace.

`java -jar ~/Downloads/proguard4.11/lib/retrace.jar -verbose out.map crashtrace.txt`

Answer (score 3):

I was having exactly the same error as you, but my fix was different - I got the Android SDK version to work.

Note that both retrace.jar and proguard.jar must be extracted into the same directory to work.

To start with I only copied retrace.jar from the android SDK and it crashed with the error above. When I copied proguard.jar to the same directory, it worked!

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:  Make sure that both retrace.jar and proguard.jar are in the same directory.**

The docs here:

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/retrace/usage.html

Say to do this:

```
java -jar retrace.jar [options...] mapping_file [stacktrace_file]
```

**Important Detail Left Out:  Make sure that both retrace.jar and proguard.jar are in the same directory.**

Otherwise you will get an odd JNI error that looks like this:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
```

Comment: where retrace.jar is located? what path?